# Is there a better way to set C++ format options in VS Code instead of packing them into one long string?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, formatting, clang++

I am using Clang C++ on macOS in VS Code and I have overridden some C++ formatting options in 'settings.json' file. I am able to set some things from the Settings UI, but for more detailed settings I have added the following entry in 'settings.json':

```
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Never, AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true, ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 2, ColumnLimit: 120, PointerAlignment: Left, AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true, SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false, AlignOperands: false, ContinuationIndentWidth: 2 }"
```

I found descriptions of these settings at [Clang Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

It seems to work properly and my C++ files get nicely reformatted when I hit Alt-F, but I was wondering if there was a nicer way to specify the settings instead of using one long string in settings.json.

For example, it would be nice if I could specify each format setting on a different line or split up the string somehow into multiple lines. I don't think splitting a string into multiple lines can be done in regular JSON files, but perhaps VS code has a way?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I have set 'C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback Style' to 'Google' in the Setting UI.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if VSCode picks up the presence of a `.clang-format` file automatically or if you have to tell it to use the file, but in any case, you'll want to use one of those.

Comment: It is possible to specify a file as the primary method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment from Frank I tried using `.clang-format` file and after some messing around I got it to work. I first tried putting .clang-format inside the `.vscode` directory in my project, but that didn't work. After reading move about [clang format](https://www.clangpowertools.com/blog/getting-started-with-clang-format-style-options.html) I moved the file to my home directory (note the file format for `.clang-format` is YAML instead of JSON) since it needs to be in the same directory or a parent directory of the file being formatted.

I don't think it was required, but I also ended up running `brew install clang-format` since I couldn't find it in my path. Once that was installed I ran `clang-format -style google -dump-config>~/.clang-format` and then made the overrides I wanted.

I was able to remove the long fallback string from `settings.json` and VS Code is still formatting nicely using my style overrides in my new `.clang-format` file.

Comment: Thank you for circling back and posting an answer after figuring it out on your own.